# Extracting a partial Cascading Style Sheet

Tags: css, stylesheet, extract

Does anyone know of any utilities / plugins that can be used to extract a partial stylesheet? I only want the classes and ID's that are used on any particular page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do it with [Dust-Me Selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the 'total picture' for styling on any given page might be coming from many style sheets as well as inline styling. If you're debugging you might find tools like FireBug helpful which examines individual elements and shows you all the styles affecting it and where they came from.

Comment: yup that's why I want a tool, the page has 12 style sheets and I only want the key styles, inherited styles etc without copying and pasting for hours.